# Access "Program Files" From Folder Picker

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to have the user give a Windows Store Application permission to *read only*, from their Program Files Folder?

When I use the `FolderPicker` class, the "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" folders are hidden. I believe this is because these folders are "system" folders, so really I suppose my question can also be phrased as:

Can the `FolderPicker` show system folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, windows store apps are meant to be very sandboxed and safe. Why do you want access to the program files folder? It's a strange requirement for a windows store app.

EDIT:
There is a way to achieve this. The windows 8 app Metro Commander can do it.

What you need to do is get the user to select the "C" drive as a folder (using the folder pciker), and you can then programatically get access to it.

Comment: I just want to interface with a legacy desktop app that creates its files within its program directory? Why is that strange?

Comment: Because a store app is meant to be downloaded from the store, so whilst it makes sense in this senario, it wouldn't make sense anywhere else.

Comment: Downloaded from the store or not, I see no reason to not allow users to grant read permissions to folders of their choosing explicitly.

Comment: And that is not prevented, just system/hidden folder aren't shown, so you must choose a parent folder, then programatically navigate it.

Comment: When I get home I will give this a shot! Thanks Ross, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues with it - I'll see if I can pull together some sample code if you do.